# good walk-through on authentication and authorization in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im new to rails and would like to implement authorization and authentication for my app, is there any good walk-through from the installation of the plug in to getting role based authorization implemented?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recomend you to check out the excellent [railscasts site](http://railscasts.com), where you can find many authentication/authorization implementation examples. I would choose between:

**Authentication**:

- [Authlogic](http://railscasts.com/episodes/60-authlogic)
- [Devise](http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise)

**Authorization**

- [Cancan](http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan)
- [Declarative Authorisation](http://railscasts.com/episodes/188-declarative-authorization)

Answer (score 1):

Try http://railscasts.com

specifically:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan
or
http://railscasts.com/episodes/188-declarative-authorization

There are lots of plugins but the above are a good place to start (and railscasts is a great resource)